# ScheduledEvent Eventhandler from Override

Tags: java, bukkit

So I want to check when a player right clicks with a book in their hand after first executing a command. I've tried to make `Runnable` running as a timer and in that scheduler checking if the player right clicks with a book in their hand. The Runnable forced me to Override the 'run' method.

This is what I've tried:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {

this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Here I want to check if the player right clicked with a book in their hand.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to register an event listener inside a task that will be run multiple times? For each event you'd like to listen to, you only need to implement one method inside a listener (the method will be called every time the event fires, no need for a repeating task).

Comment: If they run this command I want to check if they are right clicking a book until they do right click a book

Comment: Okay, that would need to be done differently though. Events can only be registered once. I would register the PlayerInteractEvent and whenever a player right clicks a book, insert the time they clicked and their names into a list. Then, whenever the player executes the command, you can check whether they recently right clicked with the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know if the player ran the command, you have to store the player's UUID somewhere. First of all you create a `Set<UUID>` which temporarily stores all the Unique ID's of all players that have executed the command, so when you see a player stored in this set, you know they executed the command. A `UUID` is a 36-character string that is unique for every player and is the same on every server. You make the `Set` like this:

```
final Set<UUID> players = new HashSet<>();
```

Next you need to make your command. I would do that like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String cl, String[] args) {
    //Check if your command was executed
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnorecase("yourCommand")){
        //Check if the executor of the command is a player and not a commandblock or console
        if(sender instanceof Player){

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            //Add the player's unique ID to the set
            players.add(player.getUniqueId());
        } 
    }
}
```

Now what you do next is listen for the `PlayerInteractEvent` to see when a player clicks the book. If you see the player is in the `Set`, you know they have executed the command. Here is how I would make that `EventHandler`:

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
    //Check if the player right clicked.
    if(event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK){
        //Check if the Set contains this player
        if(players.contains(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId()){
            //Check if the player had an item in their hand
            if(event.getPlayer().getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BOOK){
                //Remove player from the set so they have to execute the command again before right clicking the book again
                players.remove(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
                //Here you can do whatever you want to do when the player executed the command and right clicks a book.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what I've done is when the player executes the command, store them in a `Set`. Next listen for the `PlayerInteractEvent`. This is basicly a callback method called every time a player interacts. This could be when a player steps a pressureplate, when a player right or left clicks on a block or in the air etc.

In that `PlayerInteractEvent`, I check if the player is stored in that `Set`, if the player right clicked in the air or right clicked a block and check if the player has a book in their hand. If that's all correct, I remove the player from the `Set` so they have to execute the command once again to perform the same action.

Also don't forget to register events and implement `Listener`.

In case you wanna learn more about the `Set`, the Javadocs can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).